# How can I clear console before build using stack with file watch

Tags: windows, haskell, haskell-stack

When doing significant refactoring using VSCode I have found running:

`stack build --file-watch`

in the integrated Powershell terminal invaluable. I was wondering if there was a way to somehow prepend a clear terminal command so I only see the last batch of errors.

Something like:

`stack build --exec-before "cmd cls" --file-watch`

*Note exe-before is not a real stack command*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`ghcid`](https://github.com/ndmitchell/ghcid). It's a program which does exactly what you want: run the appropriate command when a file changes, clearing the screen between changes. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2018/05/19/ghcid_for_the_win.html) for more details. Plus, it looks like there's even a [Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ndmitchell.haskell-ghcid) extension which runs it directly in the IDE!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few extensions for VSCode which compile open files on the fly and populate `PROBLEMS` window with errors and warnings. From my personal experience I'd recommend [Simple GHC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dramforever.vscode-ghc-simple) which just works out of the box and quite stable.